# DataTables Hide Data Source

Tags: php, jquery, security, datatables

I have a DataTables table that loads data from

```
$table.dataTable({
    ajax: 'path/to/getData.php',
});
```

`getData.php` makes some database calls and returns `json_encode()` of the output array and DataTables is able to parse it just fine.

However if someone was to go to http://mywebsite.com/path/to/getData.php, they would be able to see all of the raw JSON data and potentially scrape it.

Is there a way to prevent people from accessing `getData.php` unless it is called by dataTables?

I'm fairly certain this will have to be a modification to the PHP code since anyone could potentially see my workaround via Javascript.

Comment: You can avoid using Ajax in your web page by using HTML sourced data instead. Use PHP to build the `<html>` table's contents, and remove the `ajax` option from your DataTable definition. There are probably several different ways to do this - but [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436739/how-to-create-html-table-in-php). See also [HTML (DOM) sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html). The end user will only have access to one page of data at a time - and will need to scrape it from the HTML instead of getting it all from a JSON response.

Comment: I was originally doing that but I have ~5000 rows and it was taking DataTables a bit of time to process everything. Doing ajax call was much faster.

Comment: I like your solution. As a side note, it helps if you tell us in your question what you have already tried - we won't suggest something that you already know is not suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `$_SESSION` variables.

At the start of the page that contains the table, I set `$_SESSION['secure'] = true;`

In my `getData.php` file, I have:

```
if($_SESSION['secure']) {
    echo json_encode($output);
    $_SESSION['secure'] = false;
}
```

To reset the `secure` session variable.